# Angular UI-Mask Letters, Numbers Only, no spaces

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular UI-Mask and I don't understand the documentation enough to do this.

I'm trying to limit a text input to lowercase letters and numbers, no spaces should be allowed.

I tried this:

`<input type="text" ng-model="path" ui-mask="[a-z0-9]">`

And that didn't work.

Also if they type in an uppercase character want it to just translate to lowercase.

Comment: check this mask may it have like you need http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/